# Implementing NSOutlineViewDataSource using MonoMac

Tags: c#, cocoa, mono, nstableview, monomac

I'm trying to implement a datasource for an `NSOutlineView`. The problem is that I don't know what type of object to return from `outlineView:child:ofItem:`.

Current code looks like this:

```
[Export("outlineView:child:ofItem:")]
public NSObject childOfItem(NSOutlineView outline, int child, NSObject item)
{
    return new MyItem();
}
```

With MyItem:

```
public class MyItem : NSObject
{}
```

**EDIT:** With this code, I get an `InvalidCastException` just after returning MyItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inherit a new type from `NSOutlineViewDataSource` then you should not **re-export** its `outlineView:child:ofItem:` selector on your own method. Instead what you should do is override the `GetChild` method that already export this selector, e.g.

```
public overrride NSObject GetChild (NSOutlineView outlineView, int childIndex, NSObject ofItem)
{
    return new MyItem ();
}
```

Note: that might not help since I have not tried it (I mostly do MonoTouch things) but do review other selectors you might be redefining/exporting in your application (to see if you should not be **override**-ing them from the base class you're inheriting from).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `NSTreeController`? It helps manage the outline view for you and is very handy. `NSTreeController` uses a class called `NSTreeNode` to represent nodes in the outline view, and each [`NSTreeNode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTreeNode_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) has a `representedObject` method that allow you to get to the model object.

In any case, if you don't want to use the `NSTreeController` or `NSTreeNode`, you can just return your model object directly. Here are some sample Objective-C code from apple guides.

```
@implementation DataSource
// Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {

    return (item == nil) ? 1 : [item numberOfChildren];
}


- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? YES : ([item numberOfChildren] != -1);
}


- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {

    return (item == nil) ? [FileSystemItem rootItem] : [(FileSystemItem *)item childAtIndex:index];
}


- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? @"/" : [item relativePath];
}

@end


@interface FileSystemItem : NSObject
{
    NSString *relativePath;
    FileSystemItem *parent;
    NSMutableArray *children;
}

+ (FileSystemItem *)rootItem;
- (NSInteger)numberOfChildren;// Returns -1 for leaf nodes
- (FileSystemItem *)childAtIndex:(NSUInteger)n; // Invalid to call on leaf nodes
- (NSString *)fullPath;
- (NSString *)relativePath;

@end


@implementation FileSystemItem

static FileSystemItem *rootItem = nil;
static NSMutableArray *leafNode = nil;

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [FileSystemItem class]) {
        leafNode = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}

- (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)path parent:(FileSystemItem *)parentItem {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       relativePath = [[path lastPathComponent] copy];
       parent = parentItem;
       }
    return self;
}


+ (FileSystemItem *)rootItem {
    if (rootItem == nil) {
        rootItem = [[FileSystemItem alloc] initWithPath:@"/" parent:nil];
    }
    return rootItem;
}


// Creates, caches, and returns the array of children
// Loads children incrementally
- (NSArray *)children {

    if (children == nil) {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *fullPath = [self fullPath];
        BOOL isDir, valid;

        valid = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir];

        if (valid && isDir) {
            NSArray *array = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:fullPath error:NULL];

            NSUInteger numChildren, i;

            numChildren = [array count];
            children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numChildren];

            for (i = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
            {
                FileSystemItem *newChild = [[FileSystemItem alloc]
                                   initWithPath:[array objectAtIndex:i] parent:self];
                [children addObject:newChild];
                [newChild release];
            }
        }
        else {
            children = leafNode;
        }
    }
    return children;
}


- (NSString *)relativePath {
    return relativePath;
}


- (NSString *)fullPath {
    // If no parent, return our own relative path
    if (parent == nil) {
        return relativePath;
    }

    // recurse up the hierarchy, prepending each parent’s path
    return [[parent fullPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:relativePath];
}


- (FileSystemItem *)childAtIndex:(NSUInteger)n {
    return [[self children] objectAtIndex:n];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfChildren {
    NSArray *tmp = [self children];
    return (tmp == leafNode) ? (-1) : [tmp count];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    if (children != leafNode) {
        [children release];
    }
    [relativePath release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

It isn't MonoMac but should be the same idea.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, you also say that I can return my model object directly. When I do that, I get an InvalidCastException, so I think it's a problem specific to MonoMac. I will try the TreeController suggestion though, but I don't think it'll help